# Issue with textarea inside a div for which display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have trouble with textarea inside a div whose display style is table-cell. You can see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetatas/u7LwW/8/). The last div has a textarea and somehow it causes an empty area below itself and above other divs.

BTW I am trying to have a structure like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetatas/u7LwW/4/). According to selection, cells will be displayed in a fixed height area with equal widths having a total 100%. Problem occurs when there is a textarea inside any div. If there is an existing component that behaves like this any recommendation will be appreciated.

### HTML

```
<div class="panes">
    <div id="pane1" class="pane">
        <div class="pane-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pane2" class="pane">
        <div class="pane-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pane3" class="pane">
        <div class="pane-content">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.panes {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.pane {
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.pane-content {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.pane-content textarea {
    display: block; /*This fix the issue in IE but other browsers still broken*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this:

```
.pane {
display: table-cell;
border: solid 1px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```